# Microservices and https certificates

Tags: api, https, microservices, self-signed

When we use microservices we have a lot of domains, so we can call each others.

Is ok to use http instead of https for microservices?
If is not ok, is ok to use self-signed certificates? Or to buy from an authority?

Answer (score 0):

Are these multiple domains public-facing?  If so, the answer is almost certainly that you should use TLS between services.  Good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48168572/7595191).

IF they are all behind a common load balancer or other ingress object, you **may** be okay leaving traffic un-encrypted.

FWIW, we use https://letsencrypt.org certificates for all our microservices, but they are all public-facing as well.